# how to access to the temporary files on cloudhub(MuleSoft)? in the path /tmp

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

Only that, I want the access to that path like  any path in my OS.
[I can't find the place where is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kPDZ.png)

Thanks.

Comment: In cloud, you use /tmp/{name} to store a temporary file. If you need to access the files use  inbound end point with the same path (file component or Mule requester) , read the same file in another flow  and check. It will work.  I believe you  wont have a access for the /tmp location in cloud. Raise ticket and check with MuleSoft. Instead of using /tmp you can use Amazon S3 and other ways suggested by @Ryan. Because you will have a complete access in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Using-Mule-3-or-Mule-4-File-Connector-fails-when-deployed-into-CloudHub

CloudHub does not guarantee that writing to disk survives hardware failures. Instead, you must use an external storage mechanism to store information. For small amounts of data, you can use the Object Store. For applications that have large data storage requirements, we recommend use of a cloud service such as Amazon S3. For temporary storage, the File connector is still available and can be used with the /tmp directory.

Comment: Github link looks broken

Comment: Updated with new link